# The admin-ajax page is the most visited page on the website

Tags: wordpress, admin-ajax

I run a small blog. And recently I started having my hosting resources limited quite often. I tried to see what is causing the problem, and I find it very suspicious that the wp-admin/admin-ajax page is the most visited page in the last few months. I already have heartbeat control.
When I run a Gtmetrix test as people suggest in the response tab all I get is 0. How can I find what is calling admin-ajax so much?

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/heartbeat-ajax-php-usage

Answer (score 0):

WordPress by default has **Heartbeat API** enabled.

In most cases, you can disable it adding this code to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'stop_heartbeat', 1 );
function stop_heartbeat() {
    wp_deregister_script('heartbeat');
}
```

Or you can limit its usage with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/heartbeat-control/

For more information: https://wptavern.com/how-to-take-control-of-the-wordpress-heartbeat-api

If GTMetrix is showing 0 as as answer, it should mean unauthenticated request or action not existing, so it can be plugin issue that requires further investigation.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Did you even read the question? He clearly says "I already have heartbeat control."

Comment: I did of course, but it was not immediately clear it was referred to plugin. I leaved it in answer as it can be useful to others.